Is there a way to have one layout per breakpoint in Highcharts
I'm currently working with Highcharts Dashboards and I've encountered a challenge related to responsive layouts.
In the edit mode of Highcharts Dashboards, you can view and adjust the layout for different breakpoints: Large, Medium, and Small devices. However, I noticed that the dashboard configuration only seems to store a single layout configuration.
Is it possible to store and manage multiple layouts within the Highcharts Dashboard configuration based on the breakpoints? Specifically, I would like to have distinct layout configurations for Large, Medium, and Small devices. If this isn't directly supported by Highcharts Dashboards, what would be the best approach to implement this functionality?
Searching through the Highcharts documentation and forums, but haven't found a clear solution or example addressing this specific requirement.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The layouts can initially be defined from the configuration object in the layouts array. You can define a couple of them over there, so it's possible to have more than one layout defined in Highcharts.

If we do it like that, would using the editor also keep the different layouts?
